# Losing seconds on xfade concat

Tags: ffmpeg

Hello guys i have some issues with xfade concat.

**I have 4 videos:**

1st has **20 seconds.**

2nd has **6 seconds.**

3rd has **5 seconds.**

4th has **9 seconds.**

Total: **40 seconds.**

`ffmpeg -y -c:v h264_cuvid -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4  -filter_complex " [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=20,format=yuv420p[1v];[1v][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=26,format=yuv420p[2v];[2v][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=31,format=yuv420p[v] " -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 10M -r 25 -map "[v]" finalVideo.mp4`

With this command I manage to get 40 seconds video, but it blocks in the middle, so it doesn't work.

`ffmpeg -y -c:v h264_cuvid -i 0.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4  -filter_complex " [0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=19,format=yuv420p[1v];[1v][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=24,format=yuv420p[2v];[2v][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=29,format=yuv420p[v] " -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 10M -r 25 -map "[v]" finalVideo.mp4`

With 2nd command I manage to make it work but now it has 38 seconds.So where does the seconds go? I used this tool, https://romander.github.io/ffmpeg-script-generator/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA2se.png

but still not good.

I want to have 40 seconds with with transitions.

Here is another try @llogan

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XU3X.png

Comment: Each fade subtracts some time, so the output can't equal the total duration of all inputs. See [Merging multiple video files with ffmpeg and xfade filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63570355/)

Comment: @llogan https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XU3X.png  i've tried like that table you wrote, still the same.

Comment: Isn't there another method, in which we don't lose seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## xfade transitions consume time

The transitions in [xfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade) take up time, so the output duration will not equal the sum of the input durations.

Simple illustration: each input is 3 seconds long and the fade transition is 1 second long where the videos overlap. Result is a 5 second output.

```
12345
===
  ===
```

## Add freeze frame to end of each video

You can use the [tpad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) filter to add more time to the video to be sacrificed to [xfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade). However, the result might look weird due to the freeze frame effect.

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=1[v0];[v0][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=10" output.mp4
```

## Use the fade + concat filters

If you want to avoid a shorter output duration then another method is to use black fades (or whatever color you want) with the [fade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) filter and concatenate with the [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i 20sec.mp4 -i 6sec.mp4 -i 5sec.mp4 -i 9sec.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]fade=t=out:st=19.5:d=0.5[fade1];[1]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=5.5:d=0.5[fade2];[2]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5[fade3];[3]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5[fade4];[fade1][fade2][fade3][fade4]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0" output.mp4
```

Comment: What if a try to add 1 second extra to each video, so when I xfade concat them, it will have exactly the seconds I need. The thing is that i cannot get rid of xfade because of transitions, so i need to find a way to make this work somehow.

Comment: i can confirm it works with adding one extra second to each video that is getting 'absorbed' to say it like that by xfade concatenation. But it works adding 1 second on videos with static images, but on non static videos I'm thinking how can I extend with one second without anybody noticing.

Comment: @Trofin You can easily extend a video with the tpad filter, although the resulting "freeze frame" may look weird during a transition.

Comment: i've used tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=1 and that extra second is 'absorbed' by xfade concat and it looks okay with transitions. I've managed to fix everything. Thank you very much !! You are the best !!