# Don't need audio transition at the time of xfade=transition effects

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I have multiple video's and joining together with effects.
Each video has its own video and audio.

When I join video and give effects, my video duration goes down by .5 seconds.

Also, audio also has transition effects and we lost few words when video joins and gives effect.

I don't want audio to have any effect and audio should be continuous with video.

Please advise the solution.

Below is the sample code.

```
ffmpeg -i 6442.mov 
-i 1339.mov 
-i 3792.mov 
-i 3332.mov 
-i 2645.mov 
-filter_complex "
[0v][1v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=2[V01];
[V01][2v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=7.5[V02];
[V02][3v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=190.44[V03];
[V03][4v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=195.94,format=yuv420p[video];
[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01];[A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02];
[A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A03];[A03][4:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" -map "[video]" 
-map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart 3914.mov
```

Please advise.

Comment: Why are you scripting a cross-fade if you don't want one? The answer would appear to be "remove that bit".

Comment: Do you want me to try after removing line [0:a][1:a] 
[A02][3:a] and remove script from last line 
-map "[audio]" and then try? Please advise.

Comment: Other than the obvious answer, "Yes"… I'm not really sure what you're looking for here. If you want a transition, you need to sacrifice part of the file to that transition period, otherwise you'd be cross-fading a black screen with no audio. If you want no transition, you have to have a butt-edit.

Comment: Related: [Losing seconds on xfade concat](https://superuser.com/q/1671254/)