# How to compute the total output duration after applying Xfade in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to understand how to get the expected total duration after applying Xfade.

The answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1671254/losing-seconds-on-xfade-concat) says:

> Simple illustration: each input is 3 seconds long and the fade
> transition is 1 second long where the videos overlap. Result is a 5
> second output.

I cant seem to take a grasp of the explanation/illustration. If there are 5 inputs (12345), and 3 seconds duration each and duration is 1 second. Isn't it the output total should be 11? Since it will overlap 4 times, between 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5. So 15-4 = 11?

So on my end, if have a video input that has durations 9.68 seconds, 10 seconds, and 8.35 seconds. How do I compute the expected total duration after applying Xfade?

Comment: You are misinterperating the example......

There are two inputs, each 3 seconds long (represented by the pair of three = signs). 12345 represents the 5 seconds total after overlapping the two inputs during the crossfade......

Determining output length when working with crossfades is pretty straight forward.....

The number of crossfades will be one less than the number of inputs. By deducting the total time of crossfades from total time of inputs we can determine total output time.

Comment: @Sark thanks for clarification. I understand the example now. Regarding the total output time, actually it's not accurate using the sum of total crossfades  deducting to total output time. That is base on the `ffprobe` duration output, the total is different. I was asking this question because I couldn't make my subtitle in right timing, and I want to pre-determine the total output with transition because I'm automating subtitle creation. Unfortunately, I just need to wait for the output then and read the output time from the output video, then just perform some maths to put it on timing.